# Some good websites to learn about JavaScript and programming architecture?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, architecture, functional-programming

I'm not sure if 'architecture' is the correct term, but I've been looking for some articles online which talk about programming design and more about how best to use languages such as JavaScript in a code design sense rather than the actual syntax itself.

I have found many websites but a lot seem to be very out dated, and I'm not sure what developments have taken place with JavaScript over the years so do not know how old is too old.

If anybody could suggest some great websites, or maybe specific articles you think would be useful, that would be highly appreciated.

I am a beginner programmer currently using JavaScript with XML and of course HTML & CSS, and I'm currently trying to get further into and learn more about web development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Must read:

> [Javascript: the good parts](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748)

Correct design, both in syntax as in 'real' code design.

Comment: I was hoping for a little more response to this question, but thank you for the recommendation. I think I'll definitely grab myself a copy of this book.

Comment: It's just the bible of JS development ;-), so no one cán provide you with a better article.

Answer (score 2):

Recently while researching for a JS architecture design project, I found these two presentations very valuable:

- [YUI Theatre Video: Nicholas C. Zakas — Scalable JavaScript Application Architecture](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/video.php?v=zakas-architecture)
- [PureMVC Standard Overview Presentation](http://puremvc.org/content/view/98/189/)

Comment: Found the Zakas presentation very useful, and also went on from there to find some great Doug Crockford videos as a result. Good call!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a starting point, have a look at http://boilerplatejs.org which is a reference architecture for large scale javascript development. Disclaimer: I'm the author of it